# Get Logged in username using a function

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class with the following function

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Performance_Dashboard.Controllers
{
public class GetLoggedInData
{
    public string ActualUser { get; internal set; }

    public string GetLoggedInDataofUser()
    {
       ActualUser= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
       return ActualUser;
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to access or see what is being returned, how do I do that?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and look at the value of the `ActualUser` variable?  Are you asking how to use the debugger?

Comment: call the function? Or im not sure what your asking

string GetUser = GetLoggedInDataofUser();

Comment: I did but my program does not go to that function that means that I have to call it right?

Comment: Yes.  You have to create an instance of GetLoggedInData and call the method from that instance.

Comment: Can I call it from a js file? @P.Brian.Mackey,

Comment: Calling C# from a JavaScript? file is way off base from where this question originated.  Please ask a new question if that's what you need next.  I believe your original question has already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> [I set a breakpoint] ... but my program does not go to that function that means that I have to call it right?

The answer is yes.  In order to hit the breakpoint you must call the method:

```
GetLoggedInData glid = new GetLoggedInData();
glid.GetLoggedInDataofUser();//Call the method.  Now the breakpoint will be hit
```

Answer (score 0):

An additional method you can use other than setting a break point is using the System.Diagnostics library to print to the output window.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Performance_Dashboard.Controllers
{
public class GetLoggedInData
{
    public string ActualUser { get; internal set; }

    public string GetLoggedInDataofUser()
    {
       ActualUser= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
       Debug.Write(ActualUser);
       return ActualUser;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works for seeing the value, but as the OP mentioned he never actually called `GetLoggedInDataofUser()`